# Cellulose from hemp seeds?

Tags: seeds

Recently I came to the discovery of this new product.

[image: vivan cellulose from hemp seeds]

Honestly I thought it were just hemp seeds, unfortunately my expectations were incorrect. Yes, it seems I really have to work on my Ukrainian...

Anyhow, now I'm stuck with this package (translation: cellulose from cannabis seeds) and I really wonder what I can do with it. I searched the webs for recipes but nothing popped up, neither when searching for recipes with just cellulose.

Anyone can here who can point me in the right direction?

Thus far I tried to make some salad with it, also I tried to dissolve it with milk which both didn't worked out that well.

Comment: Does it have any oil content?

Comment: @JCrosby nope not at all.

Answer (score 2):

**You could regulate your bowels.**

Cellulose is indigestible.  I suspect this is a fiber supplement like Metamucil or bran flakes.  If you suffer from irregularity you could use this.

I understand cellulose is used as filler for people who want to reduce carbs.  A more interesting idea than Metamucil would be to see if you can substitute it for sugar in cookies or muffins.  I am skeptical; it does not look very processed.